# jquery queue to automatically search for existing users

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping into implement a searchbox that fires an ajax request to get search results automatically. However i'd only like to do this is the user has 'finished typing' (after a delay of 2 seconds).

I thought the correct way to go around this would be to use the queue. Clearing the queue when a new letter is typed, to ensure that a settimeout could be stopped, similar to stop() on animations. but I cant seem to implement it correctly.

```
      $('.js-header-search-box').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        // stop current queued search
        $('.js-header-search-box').dequeue();
        // search
        var q = $(this).val();
        $('.js-header-search-box').queue(function () {
            setTimeout(SearchAccounts(q), 2000);
        })
    });
```

Comment: The `.queue()` is originally designed for the use of fx-functions as animation and effects and not for queing asynchronus requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.js-header-search-box').on('input propertychange paste', function (event) {
    // stop current queued search
    if (event.target.timeout)// false if undefined
        clearTimeout(event.target.timeout);

    // search
    var q = $(event.target).val();
    event.target.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        SearchAccounts(q)
    }, 2000);
});
```